# Making Jenkins build fail when Selenium tests fail

Tags: selenium, ant, jenkins

I have setup a Jenkins server for running Selenium tests. The build script is written in Ant (v 1.7.1 on CentOS 6.3) and the tests run on Sauce Labs. I execute the build via shell:

```
ant -buildfile build.xml
```

The problem is when a test fails, Jenkins marks it a success. I can avert this by setting `haltonfailure` to `true`, see:

```
<junit printsummary="yes" fork="false" haltonfailure="yes">
    <classpath refid="run.cp" />
    <formatter type="xml" usefile="true"    />
    <batchtest fork="no" todir="test-output/xml">
        <fileset dir="src/">
            <exclude name="**/*LocatorUtils*.java"/>
            <exclude name="**/*TestBase*.java"/>
            <exclude name="**/*TestUtils*.java"/>
            <exclude name="**/*Config*.properties"/>
        </fileset>
    </batchtest>
</junit>
```

However, this is not ideal because Jenkins will terminate the build on the first failure it encounters. Is it possible to check for failures once a build has completed and then mark it as failed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the `junit` task, use the `failureproperty` attribute. And then call the `fail` task with an `unless` attribute.

Further reading:

- http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html
- http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fail.html

Answer (score 1):

When the build fails, testng-failed.xml is created. You can find this xml file inside workspace/Test Report/BuildDirectory/

Here BuildDirectory is created each time. You can write a powershell script to check whether testng-failed.xml is created. If the build is success then this file will not be created.