# Jenkins Webdriver Build Status

Tags: java, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-plugins

How come `Jenkins` marks the build a success even if some of the test cases fail in the script that's linked from Webdriver?

Is there any plugin to show it has failed or would you have to change the script and make exceptions instead?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you didn't put a build condition in jenkins to fail if one of your tests fails

you can check this post to add the condition:

[Making Jenkins build fail when Selenium tests fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16792548/making-jenkins-build-fail-when-selenium-tests-fail)